# Host database (SQL Server) errors

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am trying to host my website and the database, but I have same problems and I don't know why .

This is the error message:

[image]

Comment: YOu need to change your security permissions for the folder dzsqls on your C drive. Right click it from explorer, add Everybody, give EVERYBODY full control, test - then back off the permissions

Comment: i don't have this folder "c:\dzsqls"

Answer (score 0):

Or try this:

Open Notepad, type

```
icacls "c:\dzsqls" /grant Everyone:(f)
```

Then save it as SQLPermission.bat file and double click the newly saved file. This will give full control to Everyone to the C:\dzsqls folder. When done, test your connection again. If you have trouble, report back

Comment: I don't have this folder "c:\dzsqls"